# If dark surfaces absorb/store more light/energy than light surfaces, then does dark skin, on average, store energy from light most efficiently?

Tags: physical-chemistry, chemical-biology

If darker surfaces absorb/store more light/energy per square inch than light surfaces, then does dark skin, on average, store energy more efficiently than light skin? (edited).

Comment: yes dark skin adsorbs more solar light then pale skin. Do you have a problem with that?

Comment: What do you mean by store energy from light? I don't think skin has any chlorophyll. If you mean absorb energy, yes.

Answer (score 1):

[Melanin is a chemical compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanin)(s) found in the skin and is responsible for skin pigmentation.  The darker the skin tone, the more melanin is present.  In light-toned-skin, melanin is produced as part of the tanning process when the skin is exposed to UV radiation.  Melanin is a very effective filter for UV radiation.  The more melanin present in the skin, the less light is available for light-catalyzed chemical processes that occur in the skin.

As Dissenter noted in his comment, light energy is not stored *per se* in the human body.  Rather light catalyzes certain reactions in the skin and the products of these reactions can be stored (at least for a while) for use in the body.

[Vitamin D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_D) production is an example of an extremely important light-mediated process that begins in the skin.  Vitamin D is thought to play a role in a large number of regulatory processes throughout the body ranging from bone health to cancer.  Because melanin is such an effective filter of sunlight, [non-white populations are at an increased risk of vitamin D deficiency](http://www.health.harvard.edu/newsweek/vitamin-d-and-your-health.htm).

[image]

Comment: So do darker skin surfaces utilize/absorb energy more efficiently than lighter skin or not? (a yes or no answer).

Comment: Yes, darker skin surfaces absorb light more efficiently.